# Compilation Error not displaying in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Mac Yosemite and Eclipse Luna.

I have successfully imported Maven projects into my workspace and the projects were running without any errors. The issue is Eclipse is not showing compilation error in editor or in project explorer.

Default Builders is "Maven Project Builder".

[image: String a = 10; --eclipse not showing any error]

[image: Builder]

Comment: Try Project -> Clean... and then Build.

Comment: I have tried Project->Clean but not working

Comment: Ensure Project > Build Automatically is checked

Comment: @NickJ The option is selected.
I have tried below steps also,
After Project->Clean closed eclipse and opened again.
Under Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Compiler, i have mentioned JDK 1.7, the related JRE also given.
Under Java->Compiler->Error/Warnings I have selected Restore Defaults
All the above methods could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click a project in the project explorer and choose `Maven` > `Update project`, or press 
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. Select all the relevant projects and Ok. This automatically cleans and updates the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project and go to Properties.
2. Goto Java Build Path and then select Source tab.
3. In this Tab there should be an entry with yourProjectName/src .
4. Expand this and in the Excluded-property, remove everything, i.e., it should 
   not exclude anything.
5. Remove any other entries in Source tab only yourProjectName/src should reside.

After this you may see errors in your project in package explorer.
Expand src folder and remove the package that is showing the error.

It helped me this way.